# Post and Tags model relations

Tags: node.js, model, relationship, loopbackjs

What's the relation for posts and tags?
I wonder if it's posts `hasMany` tags and tags `hasMany` posts,
 or posts `hasMany` tags and tags `hasAndBelongsToMany` posts,
 or posts `embedsMany` tags ??

I'm really confused, please help.. I'm developing a quiz app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Posts` and `Tags` are many-to-many relationship. You can think of, a post can have several tags, and a tag can be used by several posts.

You should express a `hasAndBelongsToMany` relation between `Post` and `Tag` models.

See also: [HasAndBelongsToMany relations](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/HasAndBelongsToMany-relations.html)

Comment: why not hasManyThrough relation?

Comment: `hasManyThrough` relation used when accessing distant relations via an intermediate relation. The loopbackjs docs give really good example: you have three models `Physician`, `Patient` and `Appointment `. It does not make sense to say, a physician can have several patients. But, a physician can have several appointments to see patients.